# reading from csv file java/"Could not read from the file... Stream closed"

Tags: java, csv

I  get the stream closed exception every single time I try to tun it in eclipse.As a "namef1" argument I pass the name of the file(via method).I also proivded the exact path for the CSV file.I do not really want to use CSVparser class for this unless I have to...I treated it as a normal txt file and I have no idea why this is not working(win7,eclipse,I also checked and unblocked csv file privileges-I do not know if this matters.).Is the code below correct?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
private static ArrayList<theList> parseFile1(String namef1) throws  IOException{

        File aFile= new File("C:/..."+namef1);
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(aFile);
        BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(fr);
         .............................................
```

Comment: Error/exception? Whats the issue? My code is not working is not good way to ask question.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with a stream closed exception.

Comment: It's correct as far as it goes but there is nothing here that reads a CSV file. 'Stream closed' has nothing to do with privileges: it just means you closed the stream and then kept trying to use it.

Comment: Thank you @EJP.This is the answer I needed.I simply put .close() method in a wrong place in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm the Stream closed exception was due to misplacing the close()statement.